# What is the most efficient way to find which users favorited a specific tweet?

Tags: twitter

Using the Twitter API, what would be the most efficient way to find which users favorited a specific tweet?
And also it possible to do this in retrospective, or must the streams be tapped prior the fav?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

from [twitter api docs](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/faq) :

> Favorite counts aren't available as part of tweet objects in the REST,
>   Streaming or Search APIs at this time. User streams and Site streams
>   both stream events when an authenticated user favorites tweets or has
>   their tweets favorited. Using these authenticated streaming APIs, you
>   can count favorites in real-time as they happen. This is currently the
>   only scalable means to count favorite activity.

which means that you should use [User Streams](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis/streams/user) or [Site Streams](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis/streams/site) which support streaming these events in real-time as they happen. The events indicate the tweet that was favorited and the user who favorited it.